# iOS - How to pass string from main app to widget without using app group

Tags: ios, swift, widget, ios-app-group

As title, have any idea let widget get main app data?
As I know using App group to save & load the same suite userdefault.
Does have another way to achieve this feature?
Thanks.

Comment: yes from core data and file manager you can also achieve this

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK as you just mentioned the App groups is the way to go when sharing content between your main App and your widget.

Apple is really restrict about user data safety, and don't think there is there any other way to share content without using the app group as we can see on their documentation available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1) (Sharing Data with Your Containing App)

Something that would try is using a local notification I think this might work to trigger a local notification to your extension and handle the string on the other side :)

More details available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension)